# A question was dupehammered by two users with gold badges

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775904/nullpointerexception-when-call-replaceall-method-with-regex), tagged with Java, was closed as duplicate by [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871026/reimeus) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128397/daniel-pryden), both having the Java gold badge.

I don't see in its [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49775904/timeline) that it was tagged after one close vote.

What exactly happened here? Shouldn't it be closed by only one user (the first one to VTC)?

Comment: related feature request: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)

Comment: That they not having a hammer at the time the question was closed may be another reason (doesn't apply here). Just see how it takes two mods to delete a post.

Comment: It's just the close reason system being dysfunctional as always. It is never clear who close-voted for what.

Comment: close reason chooses the most frequent (or latest in that case) reason. I saw a duplicate of this question, but cannot find it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is there a freature-request to show each reason separately? If no, I want to suggest a one.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre dupe hammer close wins over the rest always. As for regular close votes, handling their split is [explained eg here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180550/165773). And here is the [explanation why they don't want to show split details in the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239536/165773) (frankly it makes good sense to me - only thing I can't understand is why they don't expose it in timeline where their reasons apparently don't apply)

Comment: @Maroun ^^^ "explanation why they don't want to show split details in the banner" in prior comment links to that feature request (which in turn is linked to [about 20 duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54917?lq=1))

Comment: @gnat I think exactly the opposite; If OP gets more detailed reasons, they know better how to improve their post.

Comment: @Maroun nah I think it's more a matter of opinion (and anyway it was cool to see such a rare explanation of feature decline that makes at least some sense). Worth noting that exposing the split in timeline would also resolve our controversy of opinions, "if asker is smart enough to handle more detailed reasons they are also smart enough to dive into timeline and find about these". Quite a pity that this feature is unlikely to be ever implemented: they prefer to invest effort in other [Ch-ch-ch-changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/165773)

Comment: @gnat It's annoying because it used to list each reason and voter separately, and still does *in some cases*

Comment: @gnat [this explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181881/369403) by Shog9 makes a little more sense to me than the one you've referred to. I'm very much for showing it in the timeline though. Novices don't know about that anyway.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first user cast a close vote for some reason other than as a duplicate.

Comment: How could I even miss this scenario! Thanks. Is the reason available somewhere?

Comment: I've never liked that misrepresentation of actual VTC history in the summary box.

Comment: @kjhughes It should be more specific, or at least to specify the reason each user choose.

Comment: As the second user in this scenario, I can confirm that this was the case.  I'm pretty sure the close reason the first user chose was the "off-topic because lacks MCVE" one, but I can't recall for certain. To be clear: it's not a *good* question either way, and I could be convinced that off-topic was a better close reason, but dupehammering seemed like an easier/quicker fix (and slightly more likely to actually be helpful).

Comment: It's literally lying, and [I've complained about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/155739) before but nothing ever happens.